# Thread synchronization?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a list of commands that is processed concurrently on multiple threads. The list is static, each thread generates its output and does not interfere with other threads, so everything works ok so far.

Some of the commands require complex calculations on a dataset that accompanies the command. The result of the calculations is the same for all threads. At this moment each thread performs the calculations when it reaches the command but this is a waste of time and resources.

What I would like to do is to perform the calculation only once and share the results between threads. The thread that reaches first the command starts the calculation, the other threads that reach the command wait till the calculation is complete and then use the result.

I have little experience to thread synchronization and I do not know what synchronization primitives I should use for this scenario and where I should put the lock on the calculation. Can you tell me what classes (for synchronization) should I use in this scenario and where the thread should wait and on what object?

My code looks like this:

```
private void ThreadFunc(object state)
{
    Context ctx = (Context)state;

    Command cmd = ctx.CommandList;
    Processor proc = ctx.Processor;

    while (cmd != null)
    {
        switch(cmd.Type)
        {
            case CommandType.Simple:
                proc.ExecuteSimpleCommand(cmd);
                break;
            case CommandType.Complex:
                cmd.Data = ComputeData(cmd.Dataset);
                proc.ExecuteComplexCommand(cmd);
                break;
        }

        cmd = cmd.Next;
    }
}
```

The ComputeData method performs the complex calculation and the result is stored on the command.
The code has a problem at this moment because each thread sets the Data property on the same Command object but since the calculation result is the same for all threads the code works.

I was thinking of something like this but I'm not sure if it correct:

```
case CommandType.Complex:
    lock (cmd)
    {
        if (cmd.Data == null)
        {
            cmd.Data = ComputeData(cmd.Dataset);
        }
    }
    proc.ExecuteComplexCommand(cmd);
    break;
```

EDIT: I'm limited on .NET 2.0 at this moment.

EDIT 2: The list is fixed, its elements do not change. The threads only read the list, they do not modify the list.
I'll try an example: the list contains the elements A, B and C and it is processed by threads T1 and T2. When T1 reaches B, it calls ComputeData method and stores the result in a property of B. When T2 reaches B it waits till the calculation is over (assuming T1 reached B before and it already called ComputeData) and it uses the result. This is what I want to achieve.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: *"The thread that reaches first the command starts the calculation"* - sounds like [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to me (queue for commands), for results you have to use some form of blocking until notification (`Monitor.Pulse`) and preferably non-blocking collection, e.g. fixed-sized array or just named variables.

Comment: @MatthewWatson At this moment still .NET 2.0.

Comment: I've added that tag, because it will really affect your range of possible solutions.

Comment: @leppie Why did you remove the .Net 2.0 tag? It's pretty important, as you can see from the first suggestion above about using `ConcurrentQueue` (which of course isn't available in .Net 2.0)

Comment: It can be mentioned in the question text.

Comment: So, does it matter if a simple command runs in parallel while the (first) Complex command is doing that preprocessing?

Comment: @TamasIonut simple commands can run in parallel without problems. complex commands can also run in parallel (this is what I'm doing now) but the same calculation is performed on each thread and this is a waste of time.

Comment: @Surubelnita posted my answer: basically, you use Monitor.Wait for all the heavy computation threads to wait for the thread that does the heavy lifting which in turn lets all threads know that it's done with a Monitor.PulseAll;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're attempting to grab the head of the linked list and then move to the next location. Obviously the 'grab' is the issue here; it's easy to put a loop around it.

**With locks**

The easy solution is to use a lock:

```
private static object lockObject = new object();

// ...

Command current;
lock (lockObject)
{
    current = CommandList;
    CommandList = CommandList.Next;
}

// use current.
```

Alternatively, you can use a spinlock.

**Without locks**

While it's always tricky to make thread-safe code without locks, here's my attempt (WARNING: there might be bugs in here; I haven't thoroughly checked my code!):

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier(); // read barrier
var list = CommandList;

if (list != null)
{
    var next = list.Next;
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref CommandList, next, list) == list)
    {
       // execute code on 'list'.
    }
    else 
    {
       // something changed. Try again.
    }
}
```

**Let's change the question...**

Sometimes the dialogue makes things more confusing...

> The thread that reaches first the command starts the calculation, the other threads that reach the command wait till the calculation is complete and then use the result.

and

> Simple commands can run in parallel without problems. complex commands can also run in parallel (this is what I'm doing now) but the same calculation is performed on each thread and this is a waste of time.

So let's get this straight: Let's assume we have chain A->B->C with A and C simple commands and B a complex command. We want A,B to run in parallel and want to run C after B has finished. While executing B we should all wait until its done.

One simple solution comes to mind: let's assume that simple commands have no data and complex commands do have data. You've also said that the list is created before invoking it all. This means we don't have to do a lot of synchronization.

Basically you can do this as follows:

```
var current =  this.CommandList;

while (current != null)
{
    if (current.Data != null) // is it a complex command? (B)
    {
        lock (current.Data) // all threads wait here except one
        {
            if (current.Executed) // execute it once.
            { 
                // Go ahead and execute it, single threaded
                // [code]

                current.Executed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bool executeHere = false;

        // simple command.
        lock (lockObject) // shared lock object
        {
            executeHere = !command.Executed; // execute it in this thread?
            command.Executed = true;
        }

        // will be true in 1 thread only, but multiple A's/C's can be executed in parallel.
        if (executeHere) 
        {
            // execute simple command
            // [code]
        }
    }
    current = current.Next;
}
```

Comment: @Surubelnita Doesn't change a thing. If you want tasks to be processed once, you need a common state. Call it `CommandList` or something else; that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6 {
public class Context
{
    public Command CommandList { get; set; }
    public Processor Processor { get; set; }
}

public class Processor
{
    public void ExecuteSimpleCommand(Command command)
    {
    }

    public void ExecuteComplexCommand(Command command) {
    }
}

public enum CommandType
{
    Simple,
    Complex
}

public class Command {
    public CommandType Type { get; set; }
    public Command Next { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private readonly object signalObject = new object();
    private object computationResult;
    private int sharedPriority = -1;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
    }

    private void ThreadFunc(object state) {
        Context ctx = (Context)state;
        Command cmd = ctx.CommandList;
        Processor proc = ctx.Processor;

        while (cmd != null) {
            switch (cmd.Type) {
                case CommandType.Simple:
                    proc.ExecuteSimpleCommand(cmd);
                    break;
                case CommandType.Complex:
                    //each thread will atomically increment the sharedPriority; only the thread with priority=0 (we start from -1) will do the heavy computation
                    cmd.Data = ComputeData(null, Interlocked.Increment(ref sharedPriority)); //pass around your input
                    proc.ExecuteComplexCommand(cmd);

                    break;
            }

            cmd = cmd.Next;
        }
    }

    private object ComputeData(object input, int priority)
    {
        // we allow only the thread with the priority 0 to perform the heavy computation
        if (priority != 0)
        {
            // for all other threads, it will wait for the thread that got the chance to do the heavy computation to signal
            Monitor.Wait(signalObject);

            return computationResult;
        }

        //heavy computation here 
        computationResult = new object(); // .. implement your heavy logic here
        Monitor.PulseAll(signalObject); // we've computed the result, let all other threads to do use the heavy computation result

        return computationResult;
    }
}
}
```

You gotta make sure that the `computationResult` is not mutated (only read) by your threads, otherwise you will get some nasty race conditions.

Comment: you can only use wait / pulse in a `lock`. It's not necessary to use these things here; locking will automatically ensure one thread to continue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite understand the question. But the common situation is when you have a list of work items and you want to process them in multiple threads. In C# there are a few thread-safe collection that you could use. Such as `ConcurrentDictionary`, `ConcurrentBag`, `ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentStack` etc. Please see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

All these classes implement locking inside. You just need to choose the one that is more suitable for your situation. Here is a `ConcurrentQueue` example:

```
class Program
{
    static long _total;
    static ConcurrentQueue<int> _queued;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000);
        _queued = new ConcurrentQueue<int>(numbers);
        _total = 0;

        Task task1 = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue());
        Task task2 = Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue());

        Task.WaitAll(
            Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue()), 
            Task.Run(() => ProcessQueue()));

        Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", _total);
    }

    static void ProcessQueue()
    {
        int value;

        while (_queued.TryDequeue(out value))
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref _total, value);
        }
    }
}
```